# How can I create a loop to copy a series of files to their compatible folders

Tags: linux, bash

For example, files starting with the number 1 to the folder number 1 and so on…, I can do it for each one using the following command:

```
find /home/ -name '1_*_*_*_*_*_*.nii' -exec cp '{}' /home/1 ';'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this (1 to 100)?

```
for i in {1..100}; do
  find /home/ -name "${i}_*_*_*_*_*_*.nii" -exec cp '{}' /home/${i} \;
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, but I do not know why it did not work !!

Comment: I fixed the `find` command you provided and replaced single quotes with double.

Answer (score 0):

Into the source directory run this script:

```
for name in *.nii ; # find all files with a pattern and process its
do
  directory="${name%%_*}/"
  if [ ! -d "$directory" ]; then mkdir "$directory" ; fi # make directory if not exist
  cp "$name" "$directory" ; # copy file into the directory
done
```

The `${name%%_*}` removes longest matching suffix pattern.  In this case it will be all symbols before first `_`.  The result of the substitution for name `1_2_3.nii` will be `cp 1_2_3.nii 1/`.

This solution is more flexible because it automatically creates necessary folders and there's no need to give the range of files prefix.

Comment: Don't forget about double quotes in case there are file names with spaces.

Comment: Thank you very much, also it did not work, it showed this message:               cp: omitting directory ‘*.nii’

Comment: Removed single quotes at the first line --- `for name in *.nii`